# how to run file codeigniter on apache 2.2 version

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

how to run codeigniter file on apache version 2.2, when the address is opened, my codeigniter display looks like below

[image]

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask] and give full steps to reproduce, e.g. as [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It appears you don't have PHP installed or if you do you didn't restart apache to use it.